# c++ constructor and method implementation

Tags: c++

I've got stuck during this process of implementation class.
Below is my code which using g++ compile give me an error like below the code.

```
Contact::Contact(const char * name, const char * address, const char * 
 tel) {
      name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
      address = new char[strlen(address) + 1];
      tel = new char[strlen(tel) + 1];
      strcpy(this->name, name);
      strcpy(this->address, address);
      strcpy(this->tel, tel);
}
```

The error is

```
Contact.cpp:9: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Use std::string, not char arrays, new and str* functions.

Comment: Line 9 is where?

Comment: @manni66 this is line 9 -> name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];

Comment: I cannot use std::string, I've to use char arrays in this task

Comment: The error is not caused by the code you've shown.

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: Did you copy&paste your code?

Comment: @manni66 that's not quite fair. They could be brilliant teachers of C.

Comment: Joe, the Member Initializer List could help you out somewhat here. Documentation link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: @manni66 Another C++ course in name only where the teachers insist on inflicting C on people first.

Comment: Extended initializer lists require the use of curly braces. The only curly braces you have in this code are wrapping the body of the function. I can't see how this error could possibly be coming from this code.

Comment: I took a stab at compiling this code based on a reasonable guess as to the class declaration. It seems to compile fine: https://godbolt.org/g/r6FzTS

Comment: You probably meant `this->name =` rather than `name =`. But this is all horrible either way

Answer (score -1):

The error is probably because you use the same names for the parameters as for the member variables - the compiler might understand a different thing than what you want.
Rename the parameters, for example `n` instead of `name`, and you don’t need `this->`, and the error will go away.

Comment: Ok so which name i've to change, pls provide here me example from above code

Comment: Name hiding is valid and legal in C++.

Comment: Yes, @George , but not recommendable or helpful. He could make his first line `this->name =...`, and it would work too. I just tried to help him avoid such issues in the future.

Comment: That's true but I think it'd be better as a comment since it doesn't answer (the admittedly unanswerable question of the op's). Ps: The dv is not mine so I cannot revoke it :c.